# Multiple text areas with different rotation values causes borders to be very very wrong

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, text

If you have two textareas, one has a rotation value besides 0 and the other has no rotation value or a value of 0 and you 'tab' focus from the one w/rotation to the one w/out.  The border around the textArea w/out rotation will be rotated.  If you set the rotation value of the non-rotated text field to a non-zero number, even 0.01, it fixes the problem, this causes tons of other problems in text rendering though so its not a solution.

I found setting the focusThickness style to 0 removes the border, which is a good solution but not a great one, anybody got a better one?  Here is some sample code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute">
<mx:VBox width="100%" height="100%">
    <mx:TextArea id="source" width="100%" fontWeight="bold" fontSize="20" height="50" rotation="5" />
    <mx:TextArea id="dest" width="100%" height="50" />
</mx:VBox>
```

Here is what it looks like:
[alt text http://img.skitch.com/20091105-fftxukst1ncggynekatj6937nn.jpg](http://img.skitch.com/20091105-fftxukst1ncggynekatj6937nn.jpg)

Comment: Ok,
I figured out how to set the border size to 0 so it doesn't show but would prefer a better solution.

Comment: Thats an interesting bug.  After muddling about for a bit I dont think theres anything you can do besides file a bug report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a class that extends TextArea and overrides the adjustFocusRect method to fix this bug.

```
package
{
    import flash.display.DisplayObject;
    import flash.geom.Point;

    import mx.controls.TextArea;
    import mx.core.IFlexDisplayObject;
    import mx.core.IInvalidating;
    import mx.core.IProgrammaticSkin;
    import mx.core.mx_internal;
    import mx.managers.IFocusManager;
    import mx.styles.IStyleClient;

    use namespace mx_internal;

    public class TextArea2 extends TextArea
    {
        override protected function adjustFocusRect(obj:DisplayObject = null):void
        {
            super.adjustFocusRect(obj);

            var focusObj:IFlexDisplayObject = IFlexDisplayObject(getFocusObject());
            if (focusObj)
            {
                if ( !rotation ) {
                    DisplayObject(focusObj).rotation = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```