# Flex: rotating buttons and changing focus

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3, flexbuilder

I've got a problem with rotated buttons in Flex. They seem to contaminate other components' focus rectangles. 
Take the following source code, which couldn't be much simpler:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:WindowedApplication xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute">
    <mx:VBox width="100%" height="100%">
        <mx:Spacer height="100" />
        <mx:Button rotation="10" />
        <mx:TextArea rotation="0" />
    </mx:VBox>
</mx:WindowedApplication>
```

Now execute it. Click in the text area, the focus rectangle is correct. Press tab twice, the focus rectangle aroung the TextArea is rotated!

Is there a fix for this, or should I avoid rotating buttons altogether?

I'm using Flex SDK 3.5.

Thanks,

Daniel

Answer (score 2):

I as well recently stumbled upon this bug. Here's a [link to suggested fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678441/multiple-text-areas-with-different-rotation-values-causes-borders-to-be-very-very).

However, I was wondering if there's a more general solution rather then extending each and every component and overriding adjustFocusRect.

I came up with extending FocusManger and overriding the getter for focusPane as follows:

```
override public function get focusPane():Sprite
{
    var fp:Sprite = super.focusPane;
    if (fp && fp.numChildren != 0)
        fp.getChildAt(0).rotation = 0;

    return super.focusPane;
}
```

and set it as application's focus manager:

```
private function onPreinitialize():void
{
    application.focusManager = new FocusManagerEx(this);
}
```

This seems to work, though would be nice if some expert could tell if there aren't any pitfalls I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a bug in Flex SDK. I see next options:

- disable focus rectangles with focusSkin="{null}"
- implement your own skin and handle rotations correctly
- move to Spark,       since 3.5 is the (currently)
  last SDK of third       generation
- try to fix it yourself    (I feel it will be
  tricky...)

Also, you may file a bug in Adobe's tracker, but they're deep into 4-th generation of Flex.

Update: 3.6 nightly build contains this bug, too.